# how many variables, how many methods can we write in java class and how many lines of code can we write in java method?

Tags: java

Do we have any number of lines limit in a Method ,like wise limit for variable and methods in java?
And also I was getting compilation error when I was Assigning 100000 ints to one int array, is there any limit for the same?

Error in eclipse:Too many constants, the constant pool for Tst(this is class) would exceed 65536 entries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do we have any number of lines limit in a Method

[Maximum size of a method in Java 7 and 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17422480/maximum-size-of-a-method-in-java-7-and-8)

**65535 bytes Long**// But we should take care of Java coding standards, code should be readable

> ,like wise limit for variable and methods in java?

[Max name length of variable or method in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695951/max-name-length-of-variable-or-method-in-java)
[Maximum Method Name Length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425988/maximum-method-name-length)

**NO limit as such**// But we should take care of Java coding standards, code should be readable

> And also I was getting compilation error when I was Assigning 100000
>   ints to one int array, is there any limit for the same?

**100000 should be fine, should not be an issue**

SIZE 100000,

```
int num[] = new int[100000];
```

SIZE Integer.MAX_VALUE,

```
int num[] = new int[Integer.MAX_VALUE];
```

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit**

In Java, arrays internally use integers `(int not Integer)` for `index`, the `max size is limited by the max size of integers`. So theoretically it is `2^31-1 = 2147483647`, which is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. **But in recent HotSpot JVM it has been observed that the max size of array can be Integer.MAX_VALUE - 5**.

> Error in eclipse:Too many constants, the constant pool for Tst(this is
>   class) would exceed 65536 entries

Refer [Java “too many constants” JVM error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11437905/java-too-many-constants-jvm-error)

Comment: for last question,{1,2,3,....................}(if we initialize int array with 100000 integers) I was getting compilation error

Comment: Error in eclipse:Too many constants, the constant pool for Tst would exceed 65536 entries

Answer (score 0):

You can write whatever you need, since you don't reach the JVM's limit of 65535 bytes of bytecode per method. But be careful, a method with too many code lines is usually associated with a "bad" design... If you can, try always to split the tasks, make it as more specific as you can a huge method is Not always flexible, robust and reusable

Comment: Which means is there any limit per method?