# code too large and too many constants errors (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, javac

I've got a problem that I cannot resolve; I searched in web, but I didn't find a precise solution, or at least I didn't understand very well, I don't know.

Anyway, I've got Android Studio v. 2.1, and here's what I'm trying to do:

At first I created an SQLite Database overriding the `onCreate` method, than, in another override of the same method, I wrote a method that checks if the database is empty; if true, it'll add around 300000 words.
Here's this part:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Database db = new Database(getApplicationContext());
    db.open();


    if (db.queryTutteParole().getCount() == 0) {

        db.inserisciParole("pane", "no");
        db.inserisciParole("latte", "no");
        db.inserisciParole("uovo", "no");
        db.inserisciParole("farina", "no");
        db.inserisciParole("sale", "no");
        //and all the remaining words

    }

    db.close();
}
```

To clarify: `queryTutteParole()` is a method that returns a cursor of all that's in the database, and `inserisciParole()` puts the words with their value in the database.

Well, no errors with the code (I tested with only 5 words put), but if I put all the 300000+ words and I try to run it on my device, I have these errors:

[Here's the image with the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWFcu.png)

What I should do?

Thanks :)

Comment: Gradually increase the number of words to see where the errors start.

Comment: Please add the SQL tag to the post.

Comment: I would try to add those words to a string array and iterate through it.

Comment: maximum number of consts, fields, methods and another stuff in class is about 65k (2^16)

Comment: @babadaba I've already tried, but it gives the same error (in fact firstly I've done this way, than I tried with a db)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a array.xml file in your res/values folder and put your contents in it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="yourArray">
        <item>pane,no</item>
        <item>latte,no</item>
        <item>uovo,no</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

then iterate through it like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String[] yourArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.yourArray);


    if (db.queryTutteParole().getCount() == 0) {

        for (String s : yourArray) {
            String[] splittedArray = s.split(",");
            db.inserisciParole(splittedArray[0], splittedArray[1]);
        }
    }

    db.close();
}
```

Comment: Oh, I've made the array  directly in the Java file, so here's why it gave the same errors, thank you very much, this will run for sure  :D

Comment: glad to help :) if you have any further problems with this just make a comment

Answer (score 3):

See [Java "too many constants" JVM error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11437905/java-too-many-constants-jvm-error) for an explanation of why you got the error.

I would suggest trying to add the words to an array as @babadaba suggests, or put them in a map, and iterate through them.

Another solution is to read them from a file.

Comment: It doesn't work with an array, it's the same. Yes,  I'll go with the text file,  but I'll do as @danny117 said because it's better for performances in that way

Comment: Then you have to read from a file. I'm not 100% sure but a .properties file might be convenient for you to use.

Answer (score 1):

Wow you've hit max constants.  The constants are assigned a number.  You've seen it R.id.xxxxxx  In your case it ran out passed the maximum.  Store the words in a text file resource.  Read the text file and insert into the database.  There are also other hacks you have to search for them to have a pre-loaded sqlite database with the app.  The resource text file is far easier to maintain adding new words and such.